# How do I delete an Apex class in Salesforce Enterprise Edition using Eclipse?

Tags: salesforce

How do I delete an Apex class and trigger in Salesforce Enterprise Edition using Eclipse?

Answer (score 3):

In order to delete a trigger from a production org using eclipse you will need to use the following steps(assuming you have a sandbox org):

1. Through the web interface in your sandbox org, inactivate the trigger
2. Refresh your sandbox project in eclipse and deploy the inactive trigger to production
3. Refresh your production project in eclipse, right click on the trigger and select delete
4. Accept the option to delete from server

I believe the above steps will work, however I have only ever removed components from a production org using destructive changes & the Ant Migration Toolkit.

To use the [Ant Migration Toolkit](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Migration_Tool_Guide) for a destructive change you would need to setup the destructivechange.xml file to look similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>MyTrigger</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <version>21.0</version>
</Package>
```

There are full instructions on how to [propogate destructive changes](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Propagating_Destructive_Changes) on developerforce.

Comment: https://sunilkhuwal.wordpress.com/2021/03/25/how-to-delete-apex-classes-from-production/ for deleting a class in detailed description

Answer (score 3):

I had a near-duplicate question and landed here. I want to delete a class with just the Force.com IDE (Eclipse) **from my production org**. Inediger described how to deploy the destructive change set using the Ant Migration Toolkit and guessed at how to do it in the Force.com IDE. In my attempts with Force.com IDE version 20.0, Inediger's steps 3 and 4 will prevent you from deleting the class/trigger in your production org.

Here's the natural attempt to delete a class in the Force.com IDE:

- Click the class. Press delete.
- "Are you sure you want to delete file 'myClass.cls'?" ... OK
- "The requested operation will only delete the resource locally. Would you also like the resource to be deleted from the server?" ... Yes

At this point the file is deleted from your project and your dev org, but it remains in your production org (and the admin web interface won't let you delete it there) so you continue with:

- Deploy to Server.
- Enter production org credentials.
- Next. Next.
- Look for your class in the Deployment Candidates list--but it's not there!

Unfortunately, your class won't be listed with the Deployment Candidates because the Force.com IDE has already lost track of that file (because you deleted it--if you're in this boat recreate the class in your dev org and follow my instructions below).

We need to delete in production before we delete the file locally (I think we're walking the Force.com IDE through constructing one of those destructive change sets and deploying it for us):

1. Edit the class's matching *-meta.xml file (from the Force.com IDE).
2. Set the status to Deleted: <status>Deleted</status>. Save.
3. Right click your class, Force.com | Deploy to Server.
4. Enter your production org's credentials.
5. You should see your class as the only deployment candidate!
6. Check the box for "Apply Action?" to Overwrite your class.
7. Next your way through the rest of the wizard.

If you're following along in the Salesforce admin web pages you'll notice that the class disappears from your dev org after saving in step 2. It disappears from your production org when you get the green check mark after step 7.

Finally, I delete the class from the Force.com IDE as I normally would. When it asks me if I want to delete the file from the server I say no because we've already taken care of it. I also Add/Remove metadata components and uncheck the class name to get rid of the warning message.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong but when I try deploying these meta files to production I get this error: sf:INVALID_OPERATION: INVALID_OPERATION: testLevel of NoTestRun cannot be used in production organizations

Comment: It's an old answer and I haven't exercised delete in prod in a while. This approach looks legit to me and is more recent: https://www.salesforceben.com/way-to-delete-apex-classes-from-production/

Comment: Tried and tested on production and sandbox https://sunilkhuwal.wordpress.com/2021/03/25/how-to-delete-apex-classes-from-production/

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to delete the file from your project in Eclipse (not removing from the server because that doesn't work) and then you right click on the FOLDER (i.e. Triggers / Classes) and choose Deploy To Server.

When the dialog which shows want you want to deploy appears, the class/trigger in question will be highlighted as a red row, meaning you can check it for deletion from the production org.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this from Eclipse is to edit the -meta.xml file for the class you want to delete.  All you need to do is change the 'Status' field from 'Active' to 'Deleted'.

When you save the -meta.xml file the the corresponding class will immediately be deleted from your production org.  The class & .xml files will still be in your local Eclipse folder - but then you just can delete them locally.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways I have tried was to:

1) Go into the meta XML file for the trigger [in Force.com IDE] and set the status value to "Delete".

2) Then after saving that .xml file, I deploy the trigger to production.

I kow for a fact that should delete the file.  I have done it with a class file as well but unfortunately this was a test class file and I forgot to delete the other associated files that the test file provided test coverage for and so I lost significant  overall cumulative Test coverage due to this mistake.  Fortunately I saved the file before i deleted it and was able to re-deploy the modified test class back to production and all was OK again.